# How to scrape a webpage that is opened and dynamically updating without focusing on it in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html-agility-pack

I have a webpage that writes whatever I say as I'm talking. There is only the text on the page, everything else is blank. I'd like to get the text in a variable in my C# program. I tried using the HTML Agility Pack to scrape the text using the XPATH.

Here's what I tried :

```
string Url = "http://localhost:3333/";

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

string result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"speech\"]")[0].InnerText;
```

The problem is that as the text is generated by a Javascript as I speak, HTML Agility Pack doesn't "transmit" my voice and so no text is written on the page that it scrapes. And so I get no value in my variable.

I'd like to know if it is possible to transmit my voice to the page that will be scaped, using HTML Agility Pack or some other way.
If not, can I get the text from a webpage that would always be open and "listening" to me without focusing on it? How?

I've tried all the ways I know.

Comment: If you view the source of the page after you've spoken, does it show the spoken text?

Comment: Only if I open the webpage (which is not a problem as soon as I don't have to focus on it), when I speak the text goes into a  <span>. And When I finish my sentence it waits like 1 sec, and gets cleared.

Comment: I'm a little confused on your end goal.  Do you want to be able to show your webpage and use HtmlAgilityPack to parse the spoken text?  Or do you want to send generated "spoken" text to the webpage?

Comment: I'll try to explain better. Sorry for being confusing. My webpage already does Speech to text. But for that I have to speak. As HTML Agility Pack opens like its own personal webpage and then scrapes the text from that one, it's not the webpage I've spoke to, it's not the one that is currently opened in chrome. If I don't speak, there is no text in the source code, that's why I get no value in my variable. So I'd like to get the text shown on my page in  my variable, when I finish  my sentence.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to speak, and get the recognized text in my c# program.

Comment: Alright - what if you create a C# WPF or Windows Form app that has a WebBrowser Control.  When you run the program this browser goes to your website.  Then you have a timer that periodically parses the source with HtmlAgilityPack for your text.  Would something like this work for what you're trying to do?

Comment: I can give more details if so

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work :/, Because the voice doesn't go through the webpage at all. The javascript is not executed. EDIT : I think I've found a way. I used the Selenium driver, I just managed after many tries to get the text. I just need to find a way to allow using microphone without having to actually click manually on the button.